# Где и как применять паттерн проектирования Singleton(Одиночка)?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, singleton

Здравствуйте, в принципе понял суть паттерна Singleton. Но не могу понять, где и как его можно применять. Хотелось бы увидеть пару примеров с подробным описанием его применения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в общем случае всегда пытаюсь избежать использования синглтонов, так как они болтаются в глобальной области, доступны отовсюду, порождают кучу зависимостей и их сложно тестировать, но...есть парочка не сферический примером частого употребления этого патерна:

1. Класс логирования. Логгеры доступны по всему проекту и нет необходимость кучу экземпляров порождать.
2. Классы конфигураций. Загрузили 1 раз, доступно отовсюду.
3. Классы-фабрики реализованные в виде синглтонов. Скажем, вам нужно создавать различные классы, вы выносите их создание в фабрику. При создании вы назначаете объекту `id`. Если это многопоточное приложение, то есть шанс, что два объекта получат один и тот же идентификатор, если будет несколько инстансов фабрики. В общем, абстрактная фабрика, абстрактный метод и синглтон часто вместе используют.

Но, опять же. В случае с тем же классом логирования и чтением настроек можно грамотно настроить dependency injection/прокидывать ссылки на логер/класс настроек куда надо.

Comment: А к примеру использование Singleton для созданию класса для работы с БД, тоже стоит его здесь избегать?

Comment: @БалунВладимир доступ к таким shared ресурсам, как сокеты/доступ к базе тоже часто в виде синглтона делают, да.

Comment: И как же написать одиночку для целей логирования? Я попробовал привязать все экзепляры логирующего класса к одному файлу, получил сегментейшен фалид в конструкторе. Если снять static члена, отвечающего за поток, то ол комплит, но каждый экземпляр будет иметь свой поток. А если заприватить конструктор, как вообще создать экземпляр класса?